# How to change the color of navbar icon when the user is viewing a specific section of page

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, nav

I have a nav bar that looks like this on android
[image: Navbar for android]

with the following links if it was clicked

```html
<a href="#body-heading" class="nav__link  nav__link--active">
<a href="#services" class="nav__link">
<a href="#images" class="nav__link">
<a href="#" class="nav__link">
```

so what I want is, if someone is viewing the element with id `#services` on android, I need the js or css to toggle the class `nav__link--active` from Home icon and add it to Services Icon. I want to do it to every icons in the nav icon. Is there any way to do this on js or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution for you

```
<pre>
     https://codepen.io/lasjorg/pen/ZEQpKqy
</pre>
```